# After Committing UltraGrid-Row To DataBase, rows sometimes get deleted

Tags: c#, database, ultrawingrid

Problem:

I am trying to update the Database via adding a row of information directly into the grid, catching the data and committing it to the DB.

Ok so I Insert a row(s) into the UltraGrid, Close my application and restart it... Sometimes it commits the Rows and other times if i restart the application all new entries except 2(very old entries) are deleted.

Here is my Code:

Catch a reference to The Newly inserted row:

```
    private void ultraGrid1_BeforeRowDeactivate(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!first) //Ignore this step if application has just started
        {
            UltraGrid g = (UltraGrid)(sender);
            r = g.ActiveRow;
            ultraGrid1.Rows[g.ActiveRow.Index].Cells["Is Closed"].Value = false; 
        }
    }
```

Test for and Enter Key

```
    private void ultraGrid1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)(13)) //Test for ENTER key
        {
            if (r.Band.Index == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(r.Cells["ID"].Text);
                string Action = (string)r.Cells[1].Value;
                bool isChecked = (bool)r.Cells[2].Value;
                MainActionsInsert(Action, isChecked);
                UpdateTables();
            }
        }
    }
```

If key = Enter Show The Newly Entered ID value
Add it to The DB via MainActionsInsert() // Below

```
    private void MainActionsInsert(string Action, bool Checked)
    {
        OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO MainActions Values (ID, Action, BoolValue)", DataBaseConnection);
        //Add Parameters
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", GenerateID());
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Action", Action);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("BoolValue",Checked);
        //Add Command
        MainActionsAdapter.InsertCommand = Command;
        //Execute Agains DataBase
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //Accept Changes
    }
```

Execute The Insert Command via Command.ExecuteNonQuery

And Finally

```
    private void UpdateTables()
    {
        ultraGrid1.UpdateData();
        ultraGrid2.UpdateData();
        ultraGrid3.UpdateData();
        //
        minutesDataSet.AcceptChanges();
        MainActionsAdapter.Update(minutesDataSet.MainActions);
        SubActionsAdapter.Update(minutesDataSet.SubActions);
        SubActionsNotesAdapter.Update(minutesDataSet.SubActionNotes);
        //
        MainActionsAdapter.Fill(minutesDataSet.MainActions);
        SubActionsAdapter.Fill(minutesDataSet.SubActions);
        SubActionsNotesAdapter.Fill(minutesDataSet.SubActionNotes);
    }
```

Comment: Also note my statement... Sometimes old/already committed  entries get deleted from the DataBase(I have check this)'

Comment: And the rows do exist in the DB? Is is possible you are checking the DB for the rows before the insert transaction is committed, therefore they don't show up?